# Android 2.2 Galaxy S SGH-T959 kernel update with netfilter

Tags: wi-fi, kernel, samsung-vibrant

I can't seem to find a kernel update for this phone that would include netfilter. Does anyone know a different way to install netfilter on this phone?

Comment: I think the i9000 kernel has iptables/netfilter ... you might want to try one of the ROMs ported from i9000 to the Vibrant.

Answer (score 0):

The CyanogenMod aftermarket firmware supports netfilter.

You can follow the instructions from CyanogenMod's [full update guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Vibrant%3a_Full_Update_Guide) for the SGH-959/Samsung Vibrant to install CM7/9/10 (downloads for the vibrantmtd are [here](http://get.cm/?device=vibrantmtd)).